# What is the difference between real_escape_string() and mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am surprised to find out that this hasn't been asked

also is either enough to protect against SQL injection?

Thank you

Comment: Err, `real_escape_string()` isn't a PHP function for starters

Comment: @Phil Hey now, it could be a created function that does some fancy stuff in it - and it's magical because we can't see what it does. ;)

Comment: db is a mysqli. I am using real_escape_string on it @_@

does that make it mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: @amiranthist Yes, but you don't specify scope, which would be `MySQLi::real_escape_string()`, otherwise it would be known as `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using mysql or mysqli, you should switch over to PDO and use prepare statements instead of escaping it.

As requested. You should have a look at [this site](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) values (:username, :password)");
$STH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$STH->bindParam(':password', $password);
$STH->execute();
?>
```